# Keyup event is not firing while click shift+tab

Tags: javascript

Keyup event is not firing while click the shift+tab for the First element.

For Example:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="btn" tabindex="1">Tools</a>
```

Here i m writing keyup event in javascript.  But if i m clicking `shift+tab` while first element having focus, Its not working.So how to sort out this issue.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtSja/58/)

Comment: @The: Pls click shift+tab while the first input box having focus

Comment: yes. but y the keyup event is not triggering?

Comment: Your fiddle worked for both tab and shift+tab...
Still if it is not working for you, replace `.keyup()` with `.focusout()`.. That should solve.

Comment: @ShadabMehdi: Its not working while the first element having focus and also the focusout event is not working in  firefox using javascript.

Comment: Very interesting problem.  I can confirm that this does happen for me, but only in chrome.  In FF on Mac, if you keep hitting shift+tab, you never leave the window.  It just keeps focusing on the document as a whole.  Chrome is different.  If you hit shift+tab enough you will eventually break out of the window and highlight the omni-bar.  This is outside of the web page's control.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening:

- You `keydown` on the 2nd field, focus change to 1st field
- You `keyup` on the **1st field**
- You `keydown` on the 1st field, focus change to another sub-window/elements outside of the original `<body>` where your listener was attached
- You `keyup` **there** and this event is not captured

If you really want to capture that event, try put something that can be focused before 1st field, within the `<body>`. I suspect there are better solutions, but without knowing the context, that's the best suggestion I can offer.

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dz902/KtSja/60/).